# Z-Index IE bug fix?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

Does anyone know of a working fix for the ie z-index bug? I have come across a few solutions but interested to see if anyone here knows of a better fix.

Thanks!

Comment: 10K views and no one vote it up O-o I give you one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the [problem of IE6 not respecting the z-index on select controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx), then yes.

There is also a few others. I think the best method is to inform the users that IE6 has been replaced and that they would be better off using IE7, FF, or another recent browser verison, or direct them to the MS article explaining the problem and their courses of action.

You may not have this luxury, in which case, you should try using the select free or a few others that turn up in google results. It sucks, but you will have to try one of them.

Comment: broken link "select free layer"

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you are trying to do, there might not be an easy fix. Here is a [good discussion](http://mahzeh.org/?p=19) of some of your options, including cases that are not easily handled.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about [IE 6 select element z-index problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx) ,
and you happen to use jQuery for development, then you may try the convenient [jQuery bgiframe plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe) to solve it. :p

Answer (score 0):

I used the [jQuery bgiframe plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe) suggested by Honesty, and added a conditional comment to keep it from loading for other browsers.

[This post](http://jetlogs.org/2008/05/09/jquery-fix-ie-select-box-z-index-bug/) has more helpful info on implementing it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your browser is not in compatibility mode! I was at work, and IE automagically set my browser to "Display intranet sites in compatibility mode". I used the following meta-header to override this ridiculous setting:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```