# CSS dropdown list showing behind the dropdown below, IE6, IE7, absolute positioning bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position, internet-explorer-6, z-index

I'm facing one of the craziest problems I've ever found in css...

I have two CSS-jQuery horizontal dropdowns, one up and one below, displaying the drop-list when clicking on it.

The problem comes when I click the upper dropdown in IE6 and IE7, and absolute positioned element goes over relative positioned ones. Upper dropdown list (absolute) shows behing the dropdown (relative) below.

JavaScript:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    $(".menu").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".menu").show();
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$(document).click(function(){$(".menu").hide()});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button>Dropdown1 v</button>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#link">Option a</a>
            <a href="#link">Option b</a>
            <a href="#link">Option c</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button>Dropdown2 v</button>
        <div class="menu">
             <a href="#link">Option d</a>
             <a href="#link">Option e</a>
            <a href="#link">Option f</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown{float:left;display:inline;clear:left;position:relative}
.menu{position:absolute;left:0;top:22px;z-index:1}
.menu  a{display:block}

.menu{display:none;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;background:#ffffe0}
```

Here's the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AEBaW/

**SOLUTION HERE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/AEBaW/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known issue with z-index in IE.  It treats z-index differently for absolute positioned elements than it does for relative positioned elements.  It's like you have two sets of z-indexes.  You might be able to fix it by using wrappers with the same positioning, if you cannot get all your elements to use the same positioning.

EDIT 1:

http://caffeineoncode.com/2010/07/the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

EDIT 2:

[z index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z%20index%20bug)

[Z-Index IE bug fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458118/z-index-ie-bug-fix)

[Internet Explorer z-index bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug)

EDIT 3:

jQuery Solutions:

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

http://webdeveloper2.com/2010/01/how-to-fix-the-ie-z-index-bug-with-jquery/

Comment: i tried different workarounds from blogs and forums with no luck, if there is a hack, i'll appreciate

Comment: @Nacho:  If you already know it's the z-index bug, then you should have included all that information in your question.  Otherwise, we're going to be suggesting all kinds of fixes you're not going to want.

Comment: The fact is i can't know that, i've documented on the problem and there ARE workarounds, but those do not work for me

Comment: @Nacho:  It's the z-index bug.  And you'd know that after reading about your problem in all the blogs & forums.  See the link I posted within my answer.

Comment: @Nacho:  If not, I also added two links to jQuery solutions claiming to fix it.

Comment: I posted the solution on the question, thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

When I had to work with IE z-index issues the best solution I found was making sure that every single container was part of the same stacking-index.  Meaning, all elements act as layers of the same stack.  That's usually what makes IE act funny.

You can do this by adding `position:relative; z-index:auto;` to all of the containers.  You want to do this all the way up the line if possible.  This should force IE to consider everything one stack, thus layering properly.

Comment: The OP says he has both absolute and relative positioned items so he can't add "position:relative" to everything.

Comment: It's only necessary to add `position:relative` when there isn't already a `position:` tag.  By adding this to all the parent containers that **don't** have `position:` they will join the same stacking context.