# Z-Index : Internet Explorer (Z Ordering)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I am working with :
http://glustik.com/essex/index.php

And I am having trouble Z-Indexing the main logo to the front only in IE:7.

I have placed the large image div with a index of 5 and the logo with an index of 35.

I am not sure what would be making this happen?

Any Help?
James

Comment: Have you tried giving a z-index to the header div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a negative z-index to the elements it should be overlapping.

I added `z-index:-1` to `#topFrame`

and `position:relative` and `z-index:-2` to `#midFrame`

EDIT: Adding a higher z-index to #header also seems to work, as suggested by Jrod in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 can be very problematic with z-index. The most common solution is to set the containing element (the div or whatever the element with a z-index is in), and/or the element itself to `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Z-index in Explorer.  There are lots of helpful links and solutions [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033979/css-dropdown-list-showing-behind-the-dropdown-below-ie6-ie7-absolute-positioni/6034016#6034016).

- http://caffeineoncode.com/2010/07/the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
- [z index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z%20index%20bug)
- [Z-Index IE bug fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458118/z-index-ie-bug-fix)
- [Internet Explorer z-index bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug)