# IE7 Z-Index Issue (CSS DropDown)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have tried a few different fixes using JQuery and CSS Tricks, but I can't seem to get my drop down menu to lay over top of my accordion slider in IE7. It seems to work fine in any other web browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code snippets::

**HTML**

```
<div class="shell">
<div class="border">
        <div id="header">
          <h1 id="logo"><img src="" class="logo" /></h1>

          <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">      
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php?selected=1">Home</a></li> 
                <li ><a href="#">Applications</a> 
                    <ul class="sub-menu"> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li> 
                <li ><a href="#">Products</a> 
                    <ul class="sub-menu"> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Sub4</a></li> 
                    </ul> 
                </li> 
                <li ><a href="#">News/Media</a></li> 
                <li ><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
                <li ><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
            </ul>   
        </div><!--end nav-->    
<div id="accordion-1">
    <dl>
        <dt>Slide 1</dt>
            <dd>
                <h2><img src="images/accordian/efficacy.jpg" />Slide 1</h2>
                <p>Slide 1</p>
            </dd>
        <dt>Slide 2</dt>
            <dd>
                <h2><img src="images/accordian/accuracy.jpg" />Slide 2</h2>
                <p>Slide2</p>
            </dd>
        <dt>Slide 3</dt>
            <dd>
                <h2><img src="images/accordian/cost.jpg" />Slide 3</h2>
                <p>Slide 3 </p>
            </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* --------- */
/* -- Nav -- */
/* --------- */
#nav { height:43px; border-top:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;  }
.menu { padding: 7px 6px 0 0; }
.menu li { margin: 0 5px; float: left; list-style:none; position:relative; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; }
.menu a { display: block; padding:  8px 15px; margin: 0; color: #555; text-decoration: none; font-size: 15px; }
.menu .current a, .menu li:hover > a { color: #CA9800; }
.menu ul li:hover a, .menu li:hover li a { color: #555; }
.menu ul a:hover { background: #CA9800 !important; color: #fff !important; }
.menu ul { background: #eee; display: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 250px; position: absolute; top: 35px; border: solid 1px #ddd; z-index:9000 !important; }
.menu li:hover > ul { display: block; }
.menu ul li { float: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.menu ul a { font-size: 14px; }
.menu ul ul { left: 250px; top: -3px; }
.menu li.current_page_item a { color: #CA9800; }
.menu .sub-menu li.current_page_item a { color: #CA9800; }

/* --------------- */
/* -- ACCORDIAN -- */
/* --------------- */

/* UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING, DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

.easy-accordion{display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0}
.easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{margin:0;padding:0}
.easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{position:absolute}
.easy-accordion dt{margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;z-index:5;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform-origin: 20px 0px;  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);cursor:pointer;}
.easy-accordion dd{z-index:1;opacity:0;overflow:hidden}
.easy-accordion dd.active{opacity:1;}
.easy-accordion dd.no-more-active{z-index:2;opacity:1}
.easy-accordion dd.active{z-index:3}
.easy-accordion dd.plus{z-index:4}
.easy-accordion .slide-number{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:10px;font-weight:normal;font-size:1.1em;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);}


/* FEEL FREE TO CUSTOMIZE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

dd p{line-height:120%}

#accordion-1{width:800px;height:245px;padding:20px;background:#fff;margin:0 0 0 60px; z-index:1;}
#accordion-1 dl{width:800px;height:245px}   
#accordion-1 dt{height:46px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:0 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: arial, sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(../images/slide-title-inactive-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#BF8530}
#accordion-1 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(../images/slide-active.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
#accordion-1 dt.hover{color:#BF8530;}
#accordion-1 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
#accordion-1 dd{padding:25px;background:url(../images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
#accordion-1 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:10px;font-weight:bold}
#accordion-1 .active .slide-number{color:#fff;}
#accordion-1 a{color:#BF8530}
#accordion-1 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;}
#accordion-1 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
#accordion-1 .more{padding-top:10px;display:block}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post the relevant portions of your CSS and HTML within the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `position:relative;` to the part that's dropping down. According to [this](http://www.shawnpreisz.com/css/z-index-internet-explorer-7-ie7) it'll usually solve your problem.

Comment: You may also want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem

Comment: adding position: relative to the accordian div seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with z-index in IE 7.  It treats z-index differently for absolute positioned elements than it does for relative positioned elements.  It's like you have two sets of z-indexes.  You might be able to fix it by using wrappers with the same positioning, if you cannot get all your elements to use the same positioning.

[z-index bug threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z%20index%20bug)

[Z-Index IE bug fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458118/z-index-ie-bug-fix)

[Internet Explorer z-index bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug)

**jQuery Solutions:**

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

http://webdeveloper2.com/2010/01/how-to-fix-the-ie-z-index-bug-with-jquery/

Comment: Tried a few of those, perhaps I'm just not implementing it correctly. I'll take a look at a few of those other links. Thanks.